# Regexp on html cannot extraxt specific info from meta

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

Fellows I have the following string:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

That can be either

Over an html string and I want to extract the UTF-8. I tried with the follwoing code:

```
preg_match_all('/^(<\s*meta\s*) charset=[^"]\s*($>)*/ix', $contents, $matches);
```

But somehow Does not work and I do not know why.

Comment: If you are scraping, as you tagged, you are better off learning to use a parser. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly I swiched to guzzle http and got the encoding from HTTP header

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/^<meta\s[^>]*charset=["\']([^>]+)["\'])/i', $contents, $matches);
```

you've got several issues with `charset=[^"]\s*($>)*`
`[^"]` = not "
`\s*` = zero or more spaces (this is ok, but unecessary)
`($>)*` = not sure what your intent was here.  `$` anchors to the end of the string...   so you trying to match/capture zero or more (">" after the end of the string)s..  (it will always be zero)

Comment: How can I tell starts or not " in regexp

Comment: `["\']*`  :   " or ' (optional)

Answer (score 0):

Using `DOMDocument` class will be more appropriate and accurate way for such cases:

```
$html_string = '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html_string);
$charset = $doc->childNodes->item(1)->getElementsByTagName("meta")->item(0)->getAttribute("charset");

print_r($charset);  // "UTF-8"
```